# How/When is the Groovy MetaClassRegistry populated?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

I read that every POJO used in Groovy gets a MetaClass associated with it. These meta-classes are stored in the application wide metaclass registry. How are these meta-classes generated and placed in the meta-class registry? If each POJO gets its own meta-class, is there some sort of template that is used to generate these meta-classes?

Comment: Template? Each class or interface you are extending/implementing has own set of additional methods. At any time you could extend add new methods to class/interface.

Answer (score 2):

> I read that every POJO used in Groovy gets a MetaClass associated with
> it.

FYI... It isn't just POJO.  Every class has a meta class associate with it.

> These meta-classes are stored in the application wide metaclass
> registry.

That registry is represented in [groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/3.0.9/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClassRegistry.html).  You can get a reference to the registry from [GroovySystem.html#getMetaClassRegistry()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/3.0.9/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovySystem.html#getMetaClassRegistry()).

> How are these meta-classes generated and placed in the meta-class
> registry?

There is no one way.  You can write your own custom meta class and register it, Groovy registers default meta classes, you could replace a metaClass in the registry momentarily (while a unit test runs, for example) and then replace it with the original one after.

At runtime you could use methods like [MetaClassRegistry.html#getMetaClass(java.lang.Class)](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/3.0.9/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClassRegistry.html#getMetaClass(java.lang.Class)), [MetaClassRegistry.html#setMetaClass(java.lang.Class,groovy.lang.MetaClass)](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/3.0.9/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClassRegistry.html#setMetaClass(java.lang.Class,groovy.lang.MetaClass)), and [MetaClassRegistry.html#removeMetaClass(java.lang.Class)](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/3.0.9/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClassRegistry.html#removeMetaClass(java.lang.Class)) to manipulate the registry.

> If each POJO gets its own meta-class, is there some sort of template
> that is used to generate these meta-classes?

[docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClass](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClass.html) is the closest thing to a template but aside from satisfying standard compile time restrictions of having to implement all the abstract methods, there could be any arbitrary logic in a meta class one might write.